# Question not closing

Tags: support, bug

[This question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/18282/microeconomics-exercise-involving-utility-functions) shows me that it has 0 votes to close. [Review history](https://economics.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) shows it has at least 4, including one from a site moderator.

Why don't I see the close votes?

And would a moderator vote not immediately close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EconJohn reopened the question—I guess because it was edited with some effort shown.

Comment: I see. I thought I would be able to vote to close again in this case, but I cannot. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @denesp That is what I did. I just require the user to edit the question and that is what he did, if the site wishes to close it again I wont reopen it.

Comment: @EconJohn That is your privilege and I appreciate you tackling these questions. The problem is that I cannot vote on this question anymore, and I guess the other people who already voted cannot vote on it again either, so I don't think there will be enough people to vote to close it anytime soon. Perhaps consider leaving reopening decisions to the popular vote.

Comment: @denesp got ya.